# How to programmatically stop a Cypress test

Tags: cypress

I have a Cypress test that has only one testing case (using v10.9 with the test GUI):

```
describe("Basic test", () => {
  it.only("First test", () => {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:9999");
    cy.pause();
    //if(cy.get("#importantBox").contains(...) {
    //}
    //else 
    {
    Cypress.runner.stop();
    console.log("Stopping...");
    }
    console.log("Visiting...");
    cy.visit("http://localhost:9999/page1");
```

If a certain element doesn't  exist in the page, I don't want the test to continue, so I try to stop it.

Unfortunately, I can see this in the console:

> ```
> Stopping... 
> Visiting...
> ```

And the test keeps going without the necessary data...

So, can I somehow stop it without using huge if statements?

Comment: Do you want to stop Cypress from running any tests, or just skip the current test?

Comment: @agoff As there is only 1 test, they basically are the same :) I want this test to stop continue.

Answer (score 5):

Stopping the test is relatively easy, the harder part is the condition check.

Cypress runner is built on the Mocha framework, which has a `.skip()` method. If you issue it in your `else` clause and inside the Cypress queue, the test will stop.

Two ways to access `skip()`:

Using a `function()` callback gives access to `this` which is the Mocha context

```js
it('stops on skip', function() {
  ...
  cy.then(() => this.skip())    // stop here
})
```

Use `cy.state()` internal command (may be removed at some point)

```js
it('stops on skip', () => {
  ...
  cy.then(() => cy.state('test').skip())    // stop here
})
```

You should be aware that all Cypress commands and queries run on an internal queue which is asynchronous to javascript code in the test like `console.log("Visiting...")`, so you won't get any useful indication from that line.

To use synchronous javascript on the queue, wrap it in a `cy.then()` command as shown above with the `skip()` method, so to console log do

```js
cy.then(() => console.log("Visiting..."))
```